# Java hashcode change after serialization

Tags: java, hashcode

I am using java serialization to save objects into files. Since I am using hashCode() to check if the objects changed (I know, I know hash collisions may occur) can the hashcode of an object change after I load it from memory (can the hashCode of the object before it was saved in memory be different from the one I will get after I load it from memory)?

I am asking this because if my object has a variable _myOtherObject that points to another object, after I load it from memory the _myOtherObject will probably be stored in a different memory address and that will make the value of _myOtherObject change and that will make the hashcode of the object that I loaded from memory change. Is my thinking right?

Thanks.

Comment: It will depend on how you are computing the hashcode in your object. Can you post your code?

Comment: To your last question, the answer is still "it depends on how you calculate the hash code". It could change, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the hashcode is calculated.  But if the calculation involves using `Object.hashCode()` or `System.identityHashCode(Object)`, then it probably will change.

These hashes are based on object identity, and object reference `==` semantics.  The deserialized object will have a different identity to the original one, and won't be `==` to it.  Therefore the hashcode could be (and probably will be) different.

---

A second issue is that if you serialize and deserialize with different versions of classes (including different versions of library classes), that could result in different hashcodes *irrespective* of the identity issue above.  In *most* cases, the algorithm for computing a hashcode in a library class is not part of the API specification/